How to Animate 2D Eyes on a 3D mesh with interpolation?
I want to use a 3D character with a 2D face, similar to Kirby, where using 3D eyes would clash with the character's design. I'm looking for a way to animate the eyes or mouth textures by interpolating between different texture frames, like using shape keys in 3D. I want to achieve this without manually creating in-between frames and plan to implement it in a game engine, specifically Godot.

For example, if each frame of an animation of Shaq only has a single pose, I want to be able to transition from one rest frame to another by choosing a frame in between and having it automatically interpolate the motion. If this isn't possible in Blender but can be done in an art program that generates in-between frames automatically, I'd also like to know about that option.
